# using query, how can i select a column using two variables, with one of those using OR

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

Currently I have the formula below to grab the dates of attended sessions:

```
=query('Sessions'!C:P, "Select C, P Where P='Attended'")
```

Now I need to include another variable to exclude the sessions that are to be rescheduled, so it would be `where P=Attended` and `where Q=Completed or Q=Partial`.

I thought

```
=query('Sessions'!C:Q, "Select C, P Where P='Attended' and (Q='Completed' or Q='Partial')")
```

would work, but it only chose the ones that were partial. Anyone know what'll fix it?

Comment: You might just have a typo. Please share a sample sheet.

Comment: See [The correct way to publicly share a Google test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY('Sessions'!C:Q, 
 "select C,P 
  where P = 'Attended' 
    and Q matches 'Completed|Partial'")
```